# What is the difference between a hierarchical regression and a moderated regression? When is it appropriate to use them?

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction

So all my variables (X1, X2, and Y) are continuous, and there is a known negative relationship between X1 and Y from existing literature. My aim is to see whether variable X2 can moderate/affect this negative relationship between X1 on Y.

I am unsure whether to use hierarchical or moderated regression here.

Answer (score 1):

The way you describe your hypothesis

> My aim is to see whether variable X2 can moderate/affect this negative relationship between X1 on Y.

very clearly describes a regression, where an interaction effect between X<sub>1</sub> and X<sub>2</sub> on Y is of interest, since you want to know if the effect of X<sub>1</sub> on Y is different depending on X<sub>2</sub>. Moderated regression or simply moderation analysis are different names describing this type of analysis.

The standard regression formula is:
ŷ = b<sub>0</sub> + b<sub>1</sub>*X<sub>1</sub> + b<sub>2</sub>*X<sub>2</sub>
(where ŷ means the predicted value of y)

In a standard regression the goal is to predict Y by the two predictor variables X<sub>1</sub> and X<sub>2</sub>. In this model you get information about the total variance explained in Y by the model (= by X<sub>1</sub> and X<sub>2</sub> in total; R<sup>2</sup>) and information about the unique effects of each predictor on Y (typically via b<sub>1</sub> and b<sub>2</sub> or their standardised counterparts often called β).

### Hierarchical regression

In hierarchical regression the goal is to get a specific estimate of the incremental importance of one predictor or a set of predictors. This is done by simply comparing two regression models, one without and one with the predictor(s) of interest. For example:

Model 1: ŷ = b<sub>0</sub> + b<sub>1</sub>*X<sub>1</sub>

Model 2: ŷ = b<sub>0</sub> + b<sub>1</sub>*X<sub>1</sub> + b<sub>2</sub>*X<sub>2</sub>

If you then calculate the difference between the R<sup>2</sup> of Model 2 (the model with the predictor(s) of interest) minus the R<sup>2</sup> of Model 1, you get the amount of variance uniquely, i.e. solely explained by predictor X<sub>2</sub> (= ΔR<sup>2</sup>).

### Moderated regression

In moderated regression the goal is to model an interaction effect between the predictors. The model now looks like this:

ŷ = b<sub>0</sub> + b<sub>1</sub>*X<sub>1</sub> + b<sub>2</sub>*X<sub>2</sub> + b<sub>3</sub>*X<sub>1</sub>*X<sub>2</sub>

Here, in addition to the two unique effects of each predictor an interaction effect is added. Very simply put: If one finds that b<sub>3</sub> is significant, one can conclude that the effect of X<sub>1</sub> on Y is moderated by X<sub>2</sub> or equivalently that the effect of X<sub>2</sub> on Y is moderated by X<sub>1</sub>.

Thus, it really depends on your hypothesis which "type" of model you choose. But as can be seen in the basic example I gave above: Regression is an incredibly flexible tool and of course one could mix these two approaches, and for instance test the incremental importance of an interaction effect by adding it to the model later on. However, when it is only one predictor (f.i. the interaction effect) being added in an hierarchical approach, there is hardly any valuable information being gained by doing this, since the p-value of the incremental R<sup>2</sup> would be the same as the p-value of regression coefficient of the added predictor in the full model.